# Mouse navigation not working in VIM

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, command-line, options, linux-arch

I started using VIM today and I found out that we could use the mouse pointer to go to a line in vim using `set mouse=a`
But unfortunately, it is not working

here is the config file
https://pastebin.com/gXvhP3RH

kindly help me out

Comment: Make sure that your terminal supports mouse, and / or the gui you are using does.

Comment: Please clarify “not working.” Also reduce your config (say, by commenting out) to the minimal number of things necessary to demonstrate the problem

Comment: i am using Alacritty on Manjaro i3, and alacritty has mouse support. In one of the forums is came to know that I can resolve this using NVIM.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Based on your config in pastebin my solution won't solve your problem, but I had a very similar problem. In my case it was because I had the following in my vimrc: `set ttymouse=xterm2` because it used to be needed to enable the mouse for "vim in tmux session" cases. But when vim is outside of a tmux session, that particular line caused the mouse to stop working in vim. Removing that line fixed things for me. Maybe adding that line could fix things for your case?

Comment: setting "set ttymouse=xterm2" worked for me... thanks gusy